# create a very simple json format using jsonencode?

Tags: php, json

I have a table that I am querying and I retrieve one column of data.  I would like to pass this data into another script but the format should be
    [
     [23],
     [36],
     [4],
     [5],
     [56],
     [90],
     [65],
     [56]
    ]

I am getting 
       [{"col1":"1"},
        {"col1":"3"},
        {"col1":"4"},
        {"col1":"5"},
        {"col1":"6"},
        {"col1":"7"}]
using the json_encode command, I cannot find an example of such a simple layout?

Thanks for any help or pointers in the right direction.

below is my current code

```
$rows = array();

 while ($info = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $info;
    }

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Your expected format isn't JSON. So you should use something else instead of `json_encode`.

Comment: @putvande: It isn't? It looks like a perfectly good array of arrays to me.

Comment: Is `[ [23], [36], [4], [5], [56], [90], [65], [56] ]` valid JSON?

Comment: @putvande: `print_r(json_decode('[ [23], [36], [4], [5], [56], [90], [65], [56] ]'));` says it is.

Comment: @putvande Yes... Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rows[] = $info['col1'];
```

Comment: Needs another pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` creates objects from associative arrays and arrays from numerically keyed arrays. Try wrapping $info in array_values().

```
$rows[] = array_values($info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
$ arr =array ();
Foreach ($ object as $ value)
  $ arr[] = array ($ value);
```

Echo json_encode ($ arr);